# Does "dough" always mean "money" in the expression "cost you dough"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I read a sentence:

> Air power is like poker. A second-best hand is like none at all — it will **cost you dough** and win you nothing.”
>    — General George Kenney,Commander of Allied Air Forces in the Southwest Pacific, 1942-45.

In daily use, "dough" often refers to money. In this sentence, does it also mean "money"? Does "dough" always mean "money" in the expression "cost you dough"?

Comment: Yes, dough in this context would always mean money.  The only real exception would be some sort of wordplay; a joke to a baker, perhaps.

Comment: @JasonPatterson I'll upvote that answer!

Comment: @DamkerngT.  Thanks.  I sometimes wind up on here when I don't have sufficient time to write what I feel would be a proper answer, but there are questions with straightforward answers that can be answered briefly in comments.  Since the answers are sometimes needed quickly by the questioner, I leave a short (insufficient) answer as a comment and am always fine with another user providing a more thorough, similar answer in due time.  That's what happened in this case, and I'm glad that Maulik V was able to provide a good answer with a link to a proper definition and such.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying that Maulik V copied my comment into an answer or anything inappropriate in any way, shape, or form, only that the content of my comment and his answer are similar.  :-)

Comment: True! That's the reason the comment has many upvotes. I just made it as an answer because many 'skip' comments and thus, they *miss* the answer. Unfortunately, as a moderator I have 'turn answer into a comment' privilege but not the other way round! :) @JasonPatterson

Comment: @MaulikV You could post your answer as a community wiki, too. (I'm not sure if you know about this option. There is a small checkbox under the textbox your write your answer in. A community wiki can be upvoted/downloaded and accepted. The only difference is that the poster will not get any rep points from it.) I believe that it would set a good example for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cost you 'dough' means cost you 'money'.

It's an *old fashion slang* for **money**

> [dough](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dough?q=dough): *[uncountable] (old-fashioned, slang) money*

The author means that it'll cost money but in return, there's nothing.